# XSLT value-of ignores tags inside the element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file with the following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <card>
        <k>аванс</k>
        <body>
            <blockquote>аванс.</blockquote>
        </body>
    </card>
    <card>
        <k>авансыла-</k>
        <body>
            <blockquote>авансировать;</blockquote>
            <blockquote>авансылап авансом.</blockquote>
        </body>
    </card>
    <card>
        <k>авансылоо</k>
        <body>
            <blockquote>и. д. от авансыла-</blockquote>
            <blockquote>авансирование.</blockquote>
        </body>
    </card>
</root>
```

And I'm trying to sort all the cards by its `k` value with this XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
  <xsl:for-each select="root/card">
    <xsl:sort select="upper-case(k)" lang="ru"/>
      <k><xsl:value-of select="k"/></k>
      <body><xsl:value-of select="body"/></body>
  </xsl:for-each>
</root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And now the funny part: in online XSL editors, everything works fine and as expected. But because the XML file is quite big and I can't upload it, I had to download Oxygen XML Editor, and its output is a bit different. For some reason, Oxygen removes all `<blockquote>` tags and I can't understand why. How can I keep `<blockquote>` tags in my final XML?

Comment: XSLT
While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: *" in online XSL editors, everything works fine and as expected"* If it does, then you are using a faulty online editor. The expected result is `body` element containing a concatenation of all its descendant text nodes - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#constructing-simple-content

Comment: The title of your "question" (XSLT value-of ignores tags inside the element) is a true statement of fact. That's what it does. People who use it without first reading the spec should usually be using `xsl:copy-of`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following XSLT.

I am using Saxon XSLT processor v.9.7.0.15

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <card>
        <k>авансыла-</k>
        <body>
            <blockquote>авансировать;</blockquote>
            <blockquote>авансылап авансом.</blockquote>
        </body>
    </card>
    <card>
        <k>авансылоо</k>
        <body>
            <blockquote>и. д. от авансыла-</blockquote>
            <blockquote>авансирование.</blockquote>
        </body>
    </card>
    <card>
        <k>аванс</k>
        <body>
            <blockquote>аванс.</blockquote>
        </body>
    </card>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="card">
                <xsl:sort select="upper-case(k)" lang="ru"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<root>
  <card>
    <k>аванс</k>
    <body>
      <blockquote>аванс.</blockquote>
    </body>
  </card>
  <card>
    <k>авансыла-</k>
    <body>
      <blockquote>авансировать;</blockquote>
      <blockquote>авансылап авансом.</blockquote>
    </body>
  </card>
  <card>
    <k>авансылоо</k>
    <body>
      <blockquote>и. д. от авансыла-</blockquote>
      <blockquote>авансирование.</blockquote>
    </body>
  </card>
</root>
```

Comment: @xinatanil, I am glad to be helpful. I simplified the XSLT even more. Check it out. Please upvote my suggestion to Microsoft: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Answer (score 1):

If (as it seems) you are using a processor that supports XSLT 2.0 then you can do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:perform-sort select="card">
            <xsl:sort select="upper-case(k)" lang="ru"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```